# SQL command to update/increase

Tags: sql, sql-update, command

[image: Table]

I have a table here which I have just quickly created for the question purpose.

On SQL how do I increase the cost of the DVD by 20%?

Also when creating the table on SQL which data type do I use as when I try to create the table it doesn't fully show the cost e.g It only displays 1.2 (dvd) or .5 (cd).

Thank you!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `update`:

```
update t
    set price = price * 1.2
    where name = 'DVD';
```

If you want the price to show all the decimal points, then declare the column as a numeric, something like `numeric(10, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

How would you manually increase cost by 20%? You'd multiply it with 1.2:

```
update your_table set cost = cost * 1.2 where name = 'DVD';
```

Datatype should be NUMBER. It is about *displaying* those values in a desired manner, i.e. one decimal character, two, etc. Do it with TO_CHAR function and appropriate format mask. For example:

```
SQL> create table test (col number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (0.5);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (2.35);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (102.003);

1 row created.

SQL> select col, to_char(col, '990D0') r1,
  2              to_char(col, '990D000') r2
  3  from test;

       COL R1     R2
---------- ------ --------
        ,5    0,5    0,500
      2,35    2,4    2,350
   102,003  102,0  102,003

SQL>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `number` and `TOCHAR`; you then turn the number into a string, which won't react the same way (for example ordering would result in things like `1, 10, 11.., 2, 20, 21,.. 3, etc`.  The OP clearly hasn't defined the correct accuracy for their column. If they need 2 decimal places, they should be using something like `numeric(10,2)` (no idea how large of a number they need, hence the 10).

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice, I said that it is about **displaying** those values in desired format. Oracle Forms, Apex, Reports, etc. have numeric  items/fields whose property palette includes **format mask** which is - in SQLPlus - achieved by TO_CHAR. Once again - I'm not talking about storing numeric values as strings (God forbid! That's one of stupid things people do).

Comment: I see your point, but display formats should therefore really be done in the presentation layer. :)

Comment: That's exactly what I said.